# I created this but the function keeps having errors?

Tags: java, android, debugging, nullpointerexception

Basically, I'm trying to make this eating healthy app based on their BMI. The calculator is done but now I'm stuck at this where the user clicks on one of these 3 buttons and that list in the `Spinner` item and the `ImageView` changes accordingly (if user clicks breakfast button, then the spinner list and image change to breakfast and so). Even the image is not working. The app runs but when I click the button it terminates and I don't know how to fix it. if it's possible, can you guys also let me know the way I'm doing my `Spinner` will work or not?

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button Toch;
    Button BTbtn;
    Button LunchBtn;
    Button DinnerBtn;
    Button Submit;
    EditText inweight;
    EditText inheight;
    EditText inage;
    TextView BMR;
    RadioButton rdM;
    RadioButton rdF;
    ImageView maimage;
    Spinner spinner;

    /**
        Button Submit = (Butt
                * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        */
        private GoogleApiClient client;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final Button Submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Sumbit);
            final Button Toch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Toch);
            Toch.setOnClickListener(this);
            final Button BTbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTbtn);
            BTbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            final Button LunchBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LunchBtn);
            LunchBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            final Button DinnerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DinnerBtn);
            DinnerBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            //EditText
            final EditText inweight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inweight);
            final EditText inheight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inheight);
            final EditText inage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inage);

            //Text View
            final TextView BMR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BMR);
            // final TextView FDName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.FDName);
            //RadioButton
            final RadioButton rdM = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdM);
            final RadioButton rdF = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdF);

            //ImageView
            final ImageView maimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maimage);


        }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.BTbtn: {
                maimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.breakfast);
                //ArrayAdapter bList = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), android.R.array.breakfastList, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            }

            case R.id.LunchBtn: {
                maimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dinner);
                //ArrayAdapter lList = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), android.R.array.lunchList, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            }

            case R.id.DinnerBtn: {
                maimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.lunch);
                //ArrayAdapter dList = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), android.R.array.dinnerList, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            }

            case R.id.Sumbit: {
                double weight = Double.parseDouble(inweight.getText().toString());
                double height = Double.parseDouble(inheight.getText().toString());
                double age = Double.parseDouble(inage.getText().toString());

                double gender;

                if (rdM.isChecked()) {
                    gender = 66;
                    double ans = gender + (13.7 * weight) + (5 * height) - (6.8 * age);
                    BMR.setText("" + (int) ans);
                }
                if (rdF.isChecked()) {
                    gender = 655;
                    double ans = gender + (9.6 * weight) + (1.8 * height) - (4.7 * age);
                    BMR.setText("Your Calories require : " + (int) ans);
                }
            }

            case R.id.Toch: {
                inweight.setHint(R.string.chweight);
                inheight.setHint(R.string.chhight);
                inage.setHint(R.string.chage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`R.layout.activity_main`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.cmleu_000.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="Food Name:"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTbtn"
        android:text="Breakfast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/LunchBtn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radioGroup2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LunchBtn"
        android:text="Lunch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/DinnerBtn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/BTbtn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/BTbtn" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/DinnerBtn"
        android:text="Dinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/maimage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/LunchBtn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/LunchBtn" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/maimage"
        android:src="@drawable/dinner"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/qweight"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/qhight"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/qhight" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Sumbit"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Sumbit"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Sumbit"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdF"
            android:text="F"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rdM"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rdM"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rdM"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdM"
            android:text="M"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qage"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/qage"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:text="Your weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/qweight"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inweight"
        android:hint="Plase input your weight (KG)"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/qhight"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Your height"
        android:id="@+id/qhight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/inheight"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/qweight"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/qweight" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inheight"
        android:hint="Please input your height (CM)"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/qage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/inweight"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/inweight" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Your age"
        android:id="@+id/qage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/inage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BMR"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/BMR" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inage"
        android:hint="Please input your age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Sumbit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Sumbit"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Your BMR"
        android:id="@+id/BMR"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inheight"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/inheight" />

    <Button
        android:text="中文"
        android:id="@+id/Toch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/BMR"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Sumbit"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Sumbit" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_above="@+id/BTbtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
08-24 22:43:52.039 3104-3104/com.example.cmleu_000.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.cmleu_000.myapplication, PID: 3104
                                                                                   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                                       at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                                       at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                                                       at com.example.cmleu_000.myapplication.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:92)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-24 22:43:53.601 3104-3110/com.example.cmleu_000.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.662ms
08-24 22:44:10.123 3104-3110/com.example.cmleu_000.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.787ms
```

*new error after edditing

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""` This *new error* (consider posting a new question - it's FREE!) happens because `""` is a **string**, not a **double**.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined the `maimage` variable twice. The class variable `maimage` that you're trying to access in the `onClick(...)` method is `null` (it was never initialized).

To fix this, change:

```
final ImageView maimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maimage);
```

to:

```
maimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.maimage);
```

This way you will initialize the class variable instead of defining a new variable with the same name.

The same goes for all the other variables that you're defining again in the `onCreate(...)` method.

Comment: I tried but it's still having the same problem. Thank you very much for helping though. :(

Comment: @newbieprogrammer Have you changed all the variables in the `onCreate(...)` method ?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer  in that case edit your question, and check if the logcat still shows the same exception please.

Comment: yup, I have done it for all other variable and it still seems to shut down unexpectedly when I click on the button. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Marlon Regenhardt there you go, hope it helps. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer the new error is caused by one of this calls `Double.parseDouble(.....getText().toString());` make sure all the `EditText` contain valid decimal numbers. You should wrap these calls into `try{}catch(...){}` blocks to prevent this error from closing the app.

Comment: @Titus Thank you both so much! I just have to navigate to other pages from spinner now. That's all it is left. Once again, thank you both so much! :)

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt Thank you both so much! I just have to navigate to other pages from spinner now. That's all it is left. Once again, thank you both so much! :)